# Accessing member variables vs creating new object

Tags: java, object, new-operator

So I have some code which returns the min and max of an array in an object called min max. My question is inside the for loop do we need to create a new MinMax object at each iteration. Or could we just update MinMax's member variables like so:

```
globalMinMax.largest = Math.min(globalMinMax.smallest, localMinMax.smallest);
globalMinMax.smallest = Math.max(globalMinMax.largest, localMinMax.largest));
```

Instead of creating a new MinMax each time like we do on the starred line in the code below

```
private static class MinMax {
   public Integer smallest;
   public Integer largest;

   public MinMax(Integer smallest, Integer largest) {
     this.smallest = smallest;
     this.largest = largest;
   }

   private static MinMax minMax(Integer a, Integer b) {
     return Integer.compare(b, a) < 0 ? new MinMax(b, a) : new MinMax(a, b);
   }
}

public static MinMax findMinMax(List<Integer> A) {
   if (A.size() <= 1) {
      return new MinMax(A.get(0), A.get(0));
   }

   MinMax globalMinMax = MinMax.minMax(A.get(0), A.get(1));
   // Process two elements at a time.
   for (int i = 2; i + 1 < A.size(); i += 2) {
   MinMax localMinMax = MinMax.minMax(A.get(i), A.get(i + 1));
   **********Do we need to create a new object here?*****
   globalMinMax
      = new MinMax(Math.min(globalMinMax.smallest, localMinMax.smallest),
                   Math.max(globalMinMax.largest, localMinMax.largest));
   }
   // If there is odd number of elements in the array, we still
   // need to compare the last element with the existing answer.
   if ((A.size() % 2) != 0) {
      globalMinMax
       = new MinMax(Math.min(globalMinMax.smallest, A.get(A.size() - 1)),
                   Math.max(globalMinMax.largest, A.get(A.size() - 1)));
   }
   return globalMinMax;
}
```

Comment: Why is `Integer.compare(b, a) < 0` better than `b < a`?

Comment: Do you think there might be a problem? Why do you think so? Did you test your idea? Why do you need our input?

Comment: Im wondering if there is any advantage to using the new keyword instead of just accessing the object directly. Im wondering why the author made that decision, and whether or not it matters

Comment: I don't think it matters in this example, but object creation is very cheap and treating the objects as immutable can make the algorithm easier to parallelize.

Answer (score 1):

This code is too complex for what its doing. You should use the MinMax class you've generated to act as a store of the min/max of a list but should not use it during computation.

Finding the minimum/maximum of a list is as simple as:

```
int minimum = A.get(0);
int maximum = A.get(0);
for(int i=1; i < A.size(); i++){
   if(A.get(i) < minimum) minimum = A.get(i);
   if(A.get(i) > maximum) maximum = A.get(i);
}
return new MinMax(minimum, maximum);
```

If you want to incorporate the MinMax class more into the your overall program you can add a static method to the class called something like `generateMinMaxFromList` that will statically generate minMax objects from supplied Integer lists.

Answer (score 0):

Updating `globalMinMax` would be the better solution of the two provided if the data is not accessed in a multithreaded environment. You also need not spin up a lot of objects (especially inside a loop) *just to find the minimum and maximum value*. this can cause overhead when the source collection you're iterating over has a lot of elements.

However, there is one situation in which you'll want to create a new instance of `MinMax` objects within each iteration. This would be when you spin up multiple threads to act on the data.

---

*Note* - the first check within the `MinMax` method would throw an exception if the list passed in is empty. thus make a check for `A.size() == 0` as the first statement within the method and perform the appropriate action.